# NoMethodError: undefined method `digest'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working my way through the rails tutorial and I'm trying to [test a valid user login.](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#sec-testing_layout_changes)  However, I'm getting NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' when I run the test. I've looked everything over and I don't see why i'm getting this error. I've even resorted to copy/pasting the tutorial code to make sure it wasn't a spelling error or something else I missed when typing.

Here is my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  def User.digest(string)
      cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                    BCrypt::Engine.cost
      BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
end
```

and my fixture:

```
test_user:
    name: Test User
    email: testuser@example.com
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

and my test:

```
test "login with valid information" do
  get login_path
  post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                        password: 'password' } }
  assert_redirected_to @user
  follow_redirect!
  assert_template 'users/show'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
end
```

I'm pretty stumped so any advice is appreciated.

Stack trace:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<User:0x000000069b8c18>
Did you mean?  Digest
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
  from (irb):8
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Comment: Is the digest method accessible in  rails console

Comment: @rajeevmaash No. I get the same error as before when trying to call the method in the console.

Comment: can you add stack trace

Comment: @rajeevmaash added

Comment: you are calling it on an instance of user class. Not on class. That why the error.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that it does not like the function name 'digest'. When I changed the function name to 'digestx' in both the User.rb file and the users.yaml file, the tests passed